# Can I make an interval automatically update to stick to the end of a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, intervals

Basically, I want to have a graph that takes data from a specific column of a sheet but that sheet keeps getting new rows. Is there anyway to make the defined interval update to keep the limit being the last row of the sheet?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the range "Stick" to the end of the sheet by setting the data range for the whole column.  In the example below I changed the range from A1:A6 to A1:A.  In the data range and series view, it remains fixed but when you add data below, it updates the range automatically.

[image: Demo]